# Como debe ir una ruta para que cualquier url que no este registrada me lleve a una especifica en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, url, rutas

mi duda es que si ingreso una ruta que no este registrada en mi archivo `web.php` no me devuelva por defecto la pagina **404 Lo sentimos, la página que está buscando no se pudo encontrar IR A INICIO.**
quiero que en vez de eso me lleve a una url especifica, podria ser el login de la aplicacion web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eso existen las conocidas rutas o sintaxis *catch-all*, en las cuales se toma cualquier parámetro y se redirecciona a una acción determinada.

Tal vez la solución más conocida en Laravel es la siguiente:

```
Route::get('{any?}', function ($any) {
    ...
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Esta ruta debe ser la ÚLTIMA en el archivo de rutas que estés utilizando.

Answer (score 0):

Una psible forma es agregarle un slug de esta manera me lleva a la ruta que le especifico.

```
//si la ruta ingresada no es ninguna de las que este registrada lo dirige haacia el home
Route::get('/{slug?}', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
```

Solo sirve para la primera miga de pan, si se va realizar la segunda por ejemplo cuentas/cobro no funcionaria y me devuelve la pagina 404. entonces tocaria crear mas rutas con varios slug.